# Sphinx conf.py can’t find my find my external classes

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I have a folder structure that looks like this:

```
root/
—docs/
  -source/
    -_utils/
      -utils.py
    -conf.py
```

In conf.py I want to import a class from the utils.py file.

I do this

```
from _utils.utils import MyClass
```

And then in the docs directory, I do the make command.

I get a ModuleNotFound error that says the “_utils” module could not be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`conf.py` is not necessarily a normal Python module, but a specially loaded configuration file. It might not be able to do relative imports.

If you want to import your own Python code in Sphinx's conf.py solutions include

- Make your code part of a Python package and install your own package using pip, Poetry, etc. tools
- Manipulate `sys.path` or `PYTHONPATH` environment variable to include any folders where you want to import code

Comment: For the first option, would you recommend something like “sys.path.append(“./_utils”)”?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. But you nee to use absolute paths, because there is no concept of what's relative path in this case.